# convolution of x(at)*y(t) is equale to?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

I am wondering what the convolution of these 2 functions is equal:

1. $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y\left(t\right)x\left(\alpha\left(t-\tau\right)\right)$$
2. $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y\left(t\right)x\left(\alpha t-\tau\right)
   $$

I tried to use some convolution properties to check which of them are correct but it didn't come to any results.

thanks, Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of convolution appears to be incorrect.

Convolution is defined as:

$$(f*g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)g(t-\tau) d\tau $$

Rewriting your expression 1 to what I think you meant:

$$\begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(\tau)x(\alpha(t-\tau)) d\tau \\
\end{align*}$$

This is just $y(t)$ convolved with a scaled version of $x(t)$.  If we let $u(t) = x(\alpha t)$ then

$$\begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(\tau)x(\alpha(t-\tau)) d\tau &= (y*u)(t)\\
\end{align*}$$

Rewriting your expression 2 to what I think you meant:

$$\begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(\tau)x(\alpha t-\tau) d\tau \\
\end{align*}$$

This is just a scaled version of the convolution of $y(t)$ and $x(t)$:

$$\begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(\tau)x(\alpha t-\tau) d\tau &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(\alpha u)x(\alpha (t-u)) \alpha du\\
\\
&= \alpha\cdot(y*x)(\alpha t)\\
\end{align*}$$

To summarize:

Expression 1 has one operand scaled in time and the other is not.

Expression 2 has the result scaled in time and magnitude, or equivalently both operands are scaled in time and magnitude.

In the general case, where $u(t) = x(\alpha t)$:

$$(y*u)(t) \ne \alpha\cdot(y*x)(\alpha t) $$

Comment: thank you! that help a lot